# Microchip PIC18F CAN message reception problem

Tags: pic, can

I am attempting CAN communication between two nodes and can not get the receiver to transfer a message from the MAB to a readable buffer.  The nodes are identical, physically and in configuration.  I am transmitting at 40kbps.  The receiver will send the acknowledge bit and I have confirmed that a valid message is being sent with a Saleae Logic connected to PC. Also, when connected to MPLABX with PICKit3 for debugging I am able to see that neither the TXERRCNT of the trasmiter nor the RXERRCNT of the receiver are logging any errors.  I have RXB0CON, RXM1 set which means the receiver should be transferring all messages, including those with errors, to RXB0 ignoring filters and masks.  I have tried the same setting with RXB1CON and nothing is being transferred to that register either.  I am strictly using Assembly, no canned routines.  I have also tried starting with a "bootup message" of SID set to all 0's and 0 DLC prior to sending a normal message but it does not make any difference.

Hardware is PIC18F25K80 connected to MCP2561.  Bus is properly terminated with 120 ohm resistors at each node and meter shows 60 ohms on bus when nodes are not powered so no shorted or open terminators.

Thanks in advance to anyone that may offer suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the remainder of the file that didn't fit into the previous answer.  This part performs the actual sending and receiving at run time.

```
;*******************************************************************************
;
;   CAN receiving task.
;
can_task unbank              ;task start address
;
;   Wait for the software receive buffer to be empty.  Another task may be
;   reading the last received frame from the buffer.  When done with the data
;   in the receive buffer, FLAG_CANIN will be cleared.
;
wait_swbuf unbank            ;back here until software buffer ready for next frame
         gcall   task_yield  ;give other tasks a chance to run
         dbankif gbankadr
         btfsc   flag_canin  ;software CAN frame receive buffer is empty ?
         jump    wait_swbuf  ;no, back and check again
;
;   Clear the software receive buffer to all zeros.  This makes it easier later
;   to assemble the fields in the buffer from the hardware registers.
;
         dbankif gbankadr
         bcf     flag_canin_ext ;init to not extended frame
         bcf     flag_canin_rtr ;init to not remote request frame

         loadk32 canin_id, 0 ;set ID to 0
         clrf    canin_ndat  ;init number of data bytes
         clrf    canin_dat+0 ;init the data bytes
         clrf    canin_dat+1
         clrf    canin_dat+2
         clrf    canin_dat+3
         clrf    canin_dat+4
         clrf    canin_dat+5
         clrf    canin_dat+6
         clrf    canin_dat+7

wait_recv unbank             ;back here until a new CAN frame is received
         gcall   task_yield  ;give other tasks a chance to run
         dbankif comstat
         btfss   comstat, 7  ;at least one message in receive FIFO ?
         jump    wait_recv   ;no, go back and check again
;
;   Map the current receive buffer to the access bank region F60-F6Dh.  This is
;   where the fixed receive buffer 0 is located in legacy mode.  The symbols
;   RXB0xxx will therefore be used to access the buffer, even though it could
;   be any of the 8 receive buffers.
;
         dbankif cancon
         movf    cancon, w
         andlw   b'00001111' ;mask in only ID of the current receive buffer
         addlw   ecanconr0   ;merge with other control bits
         dbankif ecancon
         movwf   ecancon     ;map the current receiver buffer to access window
;
;   A new CAN frame has been received and hardware receive buffer containing it
;   has been mapped into the access bank where the fixed receive buffer 0
;   normally is.
;
         dbankif gbankadr
         btfsc   rxb0con, rtrro ;this is data frame, not remote request ?
         bsf     flag_canin_rtr ;is remote request frame
         btfsc   rxb0sidl, exid ;standard frame, not extended ?
         jump    recv_ext    ;extended frame
         ;
         ;   Standard frame.  Get the 11 bit frame ID.
         ;
         swapf   rxb0sidl, w
         rrncf   wreg
         andlw   b'00000111'
         iorwf   canin_id+0  ;set ID bits 

         rlncf   rxb0sidh, w
         rlncf   wreg
         rlncf   wreg
         andlw   b'11111000'
         iorwf   canin_id+0  ;set ID bits 

         swapf   rxb0sidh, w
         rrncf   wreg
         andlw   b'00000111'
         iorwf   canin_id+1  ;set ID bits 
         jump    done_id     ;done assembling ID
         ;
         ;   Extended frame.  Get the 29 bit frame ID.  In this case, the
         ;   extended ID bits form the low 18 bits of the ID and the standard
         ;   ID bits the high 11.
         ;
recv_ext dbankis gbankadr
         bsf     flag_canin_ext ;indicate extended frame

         movf    rxb0eidl, w
         iorwf   canin_id+0  ;set ID bits 

         movf    rxb0eidh, w
         iorwf   canin_id+1  ;set ID bits 

         movf    rxb0sidl, w
         andlw   b'00000011'
         iorwf   canin_id+2  ;set ID bits 

         swapf   rxb0sidl, w
         rlncf   wreg
         andlw   b'00011100'
         iorwf   canin_id+2  ;set ID bits 

         swapf   rxb0sidh, w
         rlncf   wreg
         andlw   b'11100000'
         iorwf   canin_id+2  ;set ID bits 

         rrncf   rxb0sidh, w
         rrncf   wreg
         rrncf   wreg
         andlw   b'00011111'
         iorwf   canin_id+3  ;set ID bits 

done_id  dbankis gbankadr    ;done assembling ID bits into CANIN_ID
;
;   Get the data bytes.
;
         movf    rxb0dlc, w
         andlw   b'00001111' ;mask in only the number of data bytes
         bz      done_dat    ;no data bytes ?
         movwf   reg2        ;save number data bytes in REG2
         sublw   8           ;compare to max valid number
         skip_wle            ;number of data bytes is within range ?
         jump    done_dat    ;skip the data bytes, something is wrong
         movf    reg2, w
         movwf   canin_ndat  ;set 1-8 number of data bytes in frame
         ;
         ;   Copy the data bytes in a unrolled loop.  It would be faster for
         ;   large frames to just copy all 8 bytes all the time.  Only the
         ;   actual data bytes are copied mostly to aid in debugging.  The
         ;   unused data bytes in the software buffer will therefore be zero.
         ;
         movff   rxb0d0, canin_dat+0
         dcfsnz  reg2
         jump    done_dat

         movff   rxb0d1, canin_dat+1
         dcfsnz  reg2
         jump    done_dat

         movff   rxb0d2, canin_dat+2
         dcfsnz  reg2
         jump    done_dat

         movff   rxb0d3, canin_dat+3
         dcfsnz  reg2
         jump    done_dat

         movff   rxb0d4, canin_dat+4
         dcfsnz  reg2
         jump    done_dat

         movff   rxb0d5, canin_dat+5
         dcfsnz  reg2
         jump    done_dat

         movff   rxb0d6, canin_dat+6
         dcfsnz  reg2
         jump    done_dat

         movff   rxb0d7, canin_dat+7

done_dat dbankis gbankadr    ;done copying all data bytes into the software buffer
         bcf     rxb0con, rxful ;mark HW buffer as empty, allow it to be re-used
;
;   Tell the rest of the system that a new CAN frame has been received.
;   FLAG_CANIN is always set.  This can be used by other parts of the system as
;   a event flag to read the CAN frame in the CANIN buffer.  This other code
;   must clear FLAG_CANIN when done so that this task can read the next received
;   CAN frame into the buffer.
;
;   For some systems, waiting for FLAG_CANIN to be noticed may be too slow.  For
;   such cases there is a callback mechnism.  When the preprocessor string
;   constant CANIN_CALLBACK is not the empty string, it is taken as the name of
;   a subroutine to call.  This routine can perform immediate action from this
;   task.  In any case, whatever code in the rest of the system handles the
;   received CAN frame must also clear FLAG_CANIN when it is done reading the
;   CANIN buffer.
;
         dbankif gbankadr
         bsf     flag_canin  ;indicate a new received frame is in the CANIN buffer

/if [> [slen canin_callback] 0] then ;callback routine defined ?
  /if callback_extern then
         extern  [chars canin_callback]
    /endif
         call    [chars canin_callback]
  /endif

         jump    wait_swbuf  ;back to wait for done with this frame

;*******************************************************************************
;
;   Subroutine CAN_SEND_INIT
;
;   Init the transmit frame state.  REG0 contains flag bits indicating the type
;   of frame:
;
;     Bit 0  -  0 = standard frame, 11 bit ID
;               1 = extended frame, 29 bit ID
;
;     Bit 1  -  0 = data frame
;               1 = remote request frame
;
;   The transmit state frame has a interlock so that only one task at a time can
;   attempt to send a frame.  This routine waits for the transmit frame state to
;   be available, then locks it.  Since this routine must always be called each
;   new CAN frame transmitted, the caller has exclusive access to the transmit
;   state until it is released by CAN_SEND.
;
         glbsub  can_send_init, noregs
;
;   Wait for the transmit frame state to not be in use, then lock it for our
;   use.
;
sendi_wait unbank
         dbankif gbankadr
         btfss   flag_cansend ;transmit frame still in use ?
         jump    sendi_avail ;no, it is available
         gcall   task_yield_save ;give other tasks a chance to run
         jump    sendi_wait  ;back to check again
sendi_avail dbankis gbankadr ;transmit frame state is not in use

         bsf     flag_cansend ;indicate it is now in use
         movff   currtask, canwtask ;save ID of task that has transmit state locked
;
;   Initialize the transmit frame state.
;
         dbankif lbankadr
         movf    reg0, w     ;get the flags byte
         andlw   b'00000011' ;mask in only the valid flags
         movwf   wr_flags    ;init transmit frame flags byte

         loadk32 wr_id, 0    ;init all the ID bits to 0
         loadk8  wr_ndat, 0  ;init number of data bytes to 0

         leaverest

;*******************************************************************************
;
;   Subroutine CAN_SEND_ID
;
;   Set the ID of the transmit frame state.  If this is a standard frame, then
;   the ID is in the low 11 bits of REG1:REG0.  If this is a extended frame,
;   then the ID is in the low 29 bits of REG3:REG2:REG1:REG0.
;
         glbsub  can_send_id, noregs

         dbankif lbankadr
         movff   reg0, wr_id+0 ;set low 8 bits of ID
         btfsc   wr_flags, 0 ;this is a standard frame ?
         jump    sid_ext     ;extended frame
;
;   Standard frame.  ID is 11 bits.
;
         movf    reg1, w
         andlw   b'00000111' ;mask in valid ID bits only
         movwf   wr_id+1     ;save ID high byte
         clrf    wr_id+2     ;clear unused ID bytes
         clrf    wr_id+3
         jump    sid_leave
;
;   Extended frame.  ID is 29 bits.
;
sid_ext  dbankif lbankadr
         movff   reg1, wr_id+1
         movff   reg2, wr_id+2
         movf    reg3, w
         andlw   b'00011111' ;mask in valid ID bits of high byte only
         movwf   wr_id+3

sid_leave unbank             ;common exit point
         leaverest

;*******************************************************************************
;
;   Subroutine CAN_SEND_DAT
;
;   Add the byte in REG0 as the next data byte in the transmit frame state.
;   Data bytes beyond what the CAN frame can contain are ignored.
;
         glbsub  can_send_dat, noregs

         dbankif lbankadr
         btfsc   wr_flags, 1 ;normal, not remote request frame
         jump    sdat_leave  ;remote request frames don't have data bytes

         movf    wr_ndat, w  ;get number of data bytes already stored
         sublw   7           ;compare to max with any room left
         skip_wle            ;still room for another data byte ?
         jump    sdat_leave  ;no
         lfsr    0, wr_dat   ;init pointer to first data byte
         movf    wr_ndat, w
         addwf   fsr0l       ;add offset to new data byte to write
         movff   reg0, indf0 ;stuff the data byte into the transmit frame buffer
         incf    wr_ndat     ;update number of data bytes stored

sdat_leave unbank            ;common exit point
         leaverest

;*******************************************************************************
;
;   Subroutine CAN_SEND
;
;   Send the frame stored in the current transmit frame state.  This routine
;   returns when the transmission has been initiated.  The actual transmission
;   may not occur until later, and may fail.  However, after this call the
;   information about the frame will have been transferred into the hardware and
;   the lock on the software transmit frame state released.
;
         glbsub  can_send, noregs
;
;   Wait for any previous frame to finish transmission.
;
snd_wait unbank
         dbankif txb0con
         btfss   txb0con, txreq ;previous transmission still in progress ?
         jump    snd_ready   ;no
         gcall   task_yield_save ;give other tasks a chance to run
         jump    snd_wait
snd_ready unbank             ;HW is ready for next transmission
;
;   Load the transmit buffer control registers sequentially starting with
;   TXB0SIDH.  The registers that will be loaded, in order, are:
;
;     SIDH
;     SIDL
;     EIDH
;     EIDL
;     DLC
;
         dbankif lbankadr
         lfsr    0, txb0sidh ;init pointer to first sequential register
         btfsc   wr_flags, 0
         jump    snd_ext
         ;
         ;   This is a standard frame, 11 bit ID.
         ;
         rrncf   wr_id+0, w
         rrncf   wreg
         rrncf   wreg
         andlw   b'00011111'
         movwf   indf0       ;set standard address bits 
         swapf   wr_id+1, w
         rlncf   wreg
         andlw   b'11100000'
         iorwf   postinc0    ;set standard address bits 

         swapf   wr_id+0, w
         rlncf   wreg
         andlw   b'11100000'
         movwf   postinc0    ;set standard address bits 

         clrf    postinc0    ;EIDH not used in standard address mode
         clrf    postinc0    ;EIDL not used in standard address mode
         jump    snd_doneadr ;done setting address bits
         ;
         ;   This is a extended frame, 29 bit ID.
         ;
snd_ext  dbankis lbankadr
         rlncf   wr_id+3, w
         rlncf   wreg
         rlncf   wreg
         andlw   b'11111000'
         movwf   indf0       ;set ID bits 
         swapf   wr_id+2, w
         rrncf   wreg
         andlw   b'00000111'
         iorwf   postinc0    ;set ID bits 

         rlncf   wr_id+2, w
         rlncf   wreg
         rlncf   wreg
         andlw   b'11100000'
         movwf   indf0       ;set ID bits 
         bsf     indf0, exide ;indicate this is a extended frame
         movf    wr_id+2, w
         andlw   b'00000011'
         iorwf   postinc0    ;set ID bits 

         movff   wr_id+1, postinc0 ;set ID bits 
         movff   wr_id+0, postinc0 ;set ID bits 
snd_doneadr dbankis lbankadr ;done setting address bits

         movf    wr_ndat, w  ;get number of data bytes
         btfsc   wr_flags, 1 ;data frame ?
         iorlw   b'01000000' ;no, remote request frame
         movwf   postinc0
;
;   Load the data bytes.
;
         movff   wr_dat+0, postinc0
         movff   wr_dat+1, postinc0
         movff   wr_dat+2, postinc0
         movff   wr_dat+3, postinc0
         movff   wr_dat+4, postinc0
         movff   wr_dat+5, postinc0
         movff   wr_dat+6, postinc0
         movff   wr_dat+7, postinc0
;
;   Write the transmit buffer control byte.  The TXREQ bit will be set to one,
;   which starts the transmission.
;
         setreg  b'00001000', txb0con
                 ; 0-------  clear transmit completed flag
                 ; -XXX----  read-only status bits
                 ; ----1---  request transmission
                 ; -----X--  unused
                 ; ------00  priority level

         dbankif gbankadr
         bcf     flag_cansend ;release lock on transmit frame state

         leaverest
```

Comment: Thank you for the code. It pointed me in the right direction. I stepped through the CAN config portion of my code in the debugger and found the problem. The RXB0CON register was being corrupted. It turned out to be an instance where the ECANCON register was being loaded with the same value twice in a row. I have no idea why that would cause this problem but it changed the contents of RXB0CON. Everything is working as expected now. Thanks again!

Comment: @Ollin Lathrop: Could you add a License to your code? Ah, and perhaps an ISBN number ;)

Comment: @Bart: Actually the code already has a license.  See my other answer, which contains the top section of the file.  The license is right at the top.  It of course also applies to the section in this answer, since it's all really the same file.

Comment: Ah Olin, thanks for the quick response. You are right. Sorry I was just joking, commenting on the length of your code example. And sorry for spelling your name incorrectly. But have you considered adding your code to a github.com repository and just linking to that? It's free, you could then version it in case of any changes and even accept pool requests, allowing others to suggest improvements.

Answer (score 2):

It's been a while since I last delved into my low level PIC 18 CAN code.  I remember there were a few non-obvious things required to get it working.  I don't remember the details at this point, so here is the source code for my PIC 18 CAN driver that I've used in several different projects:

[Argh!  The system won't let me post the whole source file here, saying that it exceeds some character limit.  So here is the first part of the file, which does the initializing.  I'll write another answer or answers to include the receiving and transmitting parts.]

```
;   ***************************************************************
;   * Copyright (C) 2009, Embed Inc (http://www.embedinc.com)     *
;   *                                                             *
;   * Permission to copy this file is granted as long as this     *
;   * copyright notice is included in its entirety at the         *
;   * beginning of the file, whether the file is copied in whole  *
;   * or in part and regardless of whether other information is   *
;   * added to the copy.                                          *
;   *                                                             *
;   * The contents of this file may be used in any way,           *
;   * commercial or otherwise.  This file is provided "as is",    *
;   * and Embed Inc makes no claims of suitability for a          *
;   * particular purpose nor assumes any liability resulting from *
;   * its use.                                                    *
;   ***************************************************************
;
;   CAN bus interface routines.  The exported routines are briefly listed here.
;   See the header comments of each routine for details.
;
;     CAN_INIT  -  One-time module initialization.  Must be first call after
;       reset.
;
;     CAN_START  -  Sets up the CAN hardware ready for use, and also starts the
;       CAN receiving thread.
;
;     CAN_SEND_INIT  -  Initialize the pending transmit frame state.  Must be
;       first call for sending any new CAN frame.  REG0 contains flags that
;       indicate standard versus extended and data versus remote request frame.
;
;     CAN_SEND_ID  -  Sets the frame ID in the pending transmit frame state.
;
;     CAN_SEND_DAT  -  Adds a data byte to the pending transmit frame state.
;
;     CAN_SEND  -  Sends the frame described by the current transmit frame
;       state.
;
;   The following global flags must be defined before this file:
;
;     FLAG_CANIN  -  Automatically set by the CAN receiving task in this module
;       whenever a new CAN frame is received.  The CAN frame data will be in the
;       global CANIN_xxx variables.  This state is only valid when FLAG_CANIN is
;       set.  New received CAN frames will be held and will not overwrite the
;       CANIN_xxx state until FLAG_CANIN is cleared.  This flag must be cleared
;       by application code outside this file when done with the CANIN_xxx state
;       for the current frame to allow new CAN frames to be received.
;
;     FLAG_CANIN_EXT  -  Indicates the current received CAN frame is in extended
;       format (29 bit ID) as apposed to standard format (11 bit ID).  This flag
;       is read-only outside this file, and is only valid while FLAG_CANIN is
;       set.
;
;     FLAG_CANIN_RTR  -  Indicates the current received CAN frame is a remote
;       request as apposed to a data frame.  This flag is read-only outside this
;       file, and is only valid while FLAG_CANIN is set.
;
;     FLAG_CANSEND  -  Part of the mutex mechanism to guarantee a single task at
;       a time is building and sending a CAN frame.  Managed in this module, but
;       may be examined by external code to see if the CAN sending mechanism is
;       currently acquired by another task and therefore whether CAN_SEND_INIT
;       will stall for a while if called immediately.
;
;   The following values can be defined before this file is included:
;
;     BITRATE  -  Preprocessor constant, type REAL.  The desired CAN bit rate in
;       bits per second.  Default = 500 Kbits/second.
;
;     CANIN_CALLBACK  -  Preprocessor constant, type STRING.  Name of routine to
;       call from internal CAN thread when a CAN frame is received.  No routine
;       is called when this constant is blank.  Default = blank (no received CAN
;       frame callback routine).
;
;     CALLBACK_EXTERN  -  Preprocessor constant, type BOOL.  Indicates that the
;       callback routine named in CANIN_CALLBACK is external to this module.
;       The default is TRUE (is external).  This constant must be created and
;       set to FALSE if the callback routine is local to prevent the code in
;       this file from generating a EXTERN reference to it, which will produce
;       a assembler error.
;
;     DEBUG_CANCFG  -  Preprocessor constant, type BOOL.  TRUE causes detailed
;       information to be shown about the automatic CAN bit timing
;       configuration calculations.  The default is FALSE, which just shows the
;       final result.
;
;     LBANK  -  MPASM constant.  0-15 bank number for local state of this
;       module.  No default, required.
;
;   This version drives the ECAN module built into the 18F4580.
;
         extern  currtask    ;ID of the currently running task
         extern_flags        ;declare global flag bits EXTERN

;*******************************************************************************
;
;   Configuration constants.
;
/if [not [exist "bitrate"]] then
  /const bitrate real = 500e3 ;CAN buts bit rate, Hz
  /endif
/if [not [exist "canin_callback"]]
  /then
    /const canin_callback = "" ;name of routine to call when CAN frame received
  /else
    /if [not [exist "callback_extern"]] then
      /const callback_extern bool = true ;default to callback routine is external
      /endif
  /endif
/if [not [exist "debug_cancfg"]] then
  /const debug_cancfg bool = false ;default to not show config select details
  /endif

stacksz  equ     32 + ntsksave ;CAN receiving task data stack size
ecanconr0 equ    b'10010000' ;base ECANCON value to map receive buffer 0
                 ; 10------  select enhanced FIFO mode (mode 2)
                 ; --0-----  FIFO interrupt when 4 buffers left (not used)
                 ; ---10000  base value to map receive buffer 0
;
;   Derived constants.
;
/const   fcanclk real = freq_osc ;clock to CAN module, bit rate generator input
lbankadr equ     bankadr(lbank) ;address within local state register bank

;*******************************************************************************
;
;   Global state.  All this state is assumed to be in the GBANK register
;   bank by other modules.
;
         defram  gbankadr

canwtask res     1           ;ID of the task that has the transmit buffer locked
         ;
         ;   Received CAN frame buffer.
         ;
canin_id res     4           ;frame ID
canin_ndat res   1           ;number of data bytes, always 0-8
canin_dat res    0           ;start of data bytes
canin_d0 res     1           ;symbols of individual data bytes for debugging
canin_d1 res     1
canin_d2 res     1
canin_d3 res     1
canin_d4 res     1
canin_d5 res     1
canin_d6 res     1
canin_d7 res     1

         global  canin_id, canin_ndat, canin_dat

;*******************************************************************************
;
;   Local state.
;
         defram  lbankadr
;
;   Info about the current transmit message.
;
wr_flags res     1           ; RTR,  EXT
wr_id    res     4           ;identifier, either 11 or 29 bits
wr_ndat  res     1           ;0-8 number of data bytes
wr_dat   res     0           ;start address of transmit data bytes buffer
wr_dat0  res     1           ;data bytes have individual labels for watch window
wr_dat1  res     1
wr_dat2  res     1
wr_dat3  res     1
wr_dat4  res     1
wr_dat5  res     1
wr_dat6  res     1
wr_dat7  res     1
;
;   CAN receiving task data stack.  Since this is only accessed indirectly via
;   pointer registers, the bank does not need to be known at assembly time.  It
;   is therefore put in a separate section to allow the linker to place it
;   separately from other variables.
;
.can_stack udata
stack_can res    stacksz     ;CAN receiving task data stack


.can     code

;*******************************************************************************
;
;   Subroutine CAN_INIT
;
;   Initialize the hardware and software state managed by this module.
;
         glbsub  can_init, noregs

         setreg  b'00110000', cancon ;disable the CAN module
                 ; 001-----  disable mode
                 ; ---1----  abort all pending transmissions
                 ; ----XXXX  not relevant when module disabled

         setreg  b'00100000', ciocon
                 ; XX------  unused
                 ; --1-----  CANTX pin will always be driven, recessive or not
                 ; ---0----  disable CAN capture into CCP1
                 ; ----XXXX  unused

         leaverest

;*******************************************************************************
;
;   Subroutine CAN_START
;
;   Set up the CAN hardware for operation and start up the CAN reading thread.
;   The rest of the system must not attempt CAN operations before this routine
;   is called.
;
         glbsub  can_start, regf0 | regf1 | regf2 | regf3 | regf4

         dbankif gbankadr
         bcf     flag_canin  ;init software received CAN frame buffer to empty
;
;   Set the CAN module into configuration mode.  Mode changes are requested via
;   the CANCON register, but do not necessarily take effect immediately.  The
;   actual mode is indicated in the CANSTAT register.
;
         setreg  b'10010000', cancon ;request configuration mode
                 ; 100-----  request configuration mode
                 ; ---1----  abort any pending transmissions
                 ; ----XXXX  read-only bits in mode 2
wait_cfgmode unbank          ;back here until entered configuration mode
         dbankif canstat
         movf    canstat, w
         andlw   b'11100000' ;mask in only the current mode bits
         xorlw   b'10000000' ;compare to config mode
         bz      have_cfgmode ;in config mode ?
         gcall   task_yield_save ;give other tasks a chance to run
         jump    wait_cfgmode ;back to check current mode again
have_cfgmode unbank          ;CAN module is in configuration mode

         setreg  ecanconr0, ecancon ;set enhanced FIFO mode (mode 2)
;
;   Configure the bit timing.  The bit rate is defined by the constant BITRATE,
;   and is derived from the clock into the CAN module, which is the instruction
;   clock in this case.  The frequency of this oscillator is defined by the
;   constant FCANCLK.
;
;   CAN bits are divided into time segments, each defined in terms of the number
;   of time quanta.  The length of time quanta is determined by the oscillator
;   frequency and the baud rate divider setup.  The MCP2515 requires a minimum
;   of 5 time quanta per bit, but we require 9 for reliability.  The maximum
;   allowed is 25 time quanta per bit.  The time quanta budget for a bit is
;   allocated between the various bit segments as follows:
;
;     Sync  -  Always 1.
;
;     Propagation  -  1-8, we require at least 2.
;
;     Phase1  -  1-8, we require at least 3.
;
;     Phase2  -  2-8, we require at least 3.
;
;   See the manual for details on the meaning of these segments.
;
/var new tqbit integer       ;time quanta per whole bit, 9-25
/var new tqprop integer      ;time quanta per propagation segment, 2-8
/var new tqph1 integer       ;time quanta per phase 1 segment, 3-8
/var new tqph2 integer       ;time quanta per phase 2 segment, 3-8
/var new bdiv integer        ;Fosc/2 divider to make time quanta rate, 1-64
/var new ferr real           ;CAN bit frequency error fraction

/var new ii integer          ;scratch integers
/var new jj integer
/var new r real              ;scratch floating point
/var new r2 real
/var new r3 real
/var new s1 string           ;scratch strings
/var new s2 string
/var new s3 string
//
//   Determine the bit rate setup.  The TQ frequency is (FCANCLK/2)/BDIV, with
//   BDIV constrained to 1-64.  The BDIV value resulting in the smallest
//   frequency error will be chosen, within the constraint that there must be
//   9 to 25 time quanta per bit.
//
/set bdiv 0                  ;init to no usable BDIV value found
/set ii 1                    ;init trial BDIV value
/set ferr 1.0                ;init to large frequency error so far
/block                       ;back here to try each new possible BDIV value
  /set r [/ fcanclk [* 2 ii]] ;TQ frequency for the divisor value in II
  /set jj [rnd [/ r bitrate]] ;best whole time quanta per bit for this divisor
  /set jj [if [= jj 9] jj 9] ;clip to min usable value
  /set r2 [/ r jj]           ;resulting actual bit frequency
  /set r3 [/ [abs [- bitrate r2]] bitrate] ;make error fraction
  /if [ ferr 0.015] then      ;bit rate error too large to work ?
  /show "  ERROR: Bit rate of " [eng bitrate] "Hz not possible with CAN clock of " [eng fcanclk] "Hz."
         error   CAN bit rate
         end
  /stop
  /endif
/if [> ferr 0.0085] then     ;error more than half allotted total of 1.7%
  /show "  WARNING: High CAN bit rate error from desired."
  /endif

/set r [/ fcanclk [* 2 bdiv tqbit]] ;actual bit frequency, Hz
/set s3 [fp [* ferr 100] "sig 1 mxl 6 rit 2"] ;bit frequence error in percent
/show "  CAN clock " [eng fcanclk] "Hz, bit freq " [eng r] "Hz (" s3 "% err), " tqbit " TQ/bit"
//
//   The bit rate setup has been determined.  There are TQBIT time quanta per
//   bit, which is guaranteed to be in the range of 9 to 25.
//
//   Now divvy up the time quanta to the various segements of the bit time.
//
/set tqprop 2                ;set the configurable segments to their minimum durations
/set tqph1 3
/set tqph2 3
/set ii [- tqbit [+ 1 tqprop tqph1 tqph2]] ;left over availabe TQs.

/block                       ;back here until all TQs are assigned
  /if [
                 ; ---X----  unused
                 ; ----1---  accept standard or extended according to filters
                 ; -----X--  unused
                 ; ------00  acceptance mask 0 bits 

         setreg  b'00000000', rxm0sidh
                 ; 00000000  acceptance mask 0 bits 

         setreg  b'00000000', rxm0eidl
                 ; 00000000  acceptance mask 0 bits 

         setreg  b'00000000', rxm0eidh
                 ; 00000000  acceptance mask 0 bits 

         setreg  b'00001000', rxm1sidl
                 ; 000-----  acceptance mask 1 bits 
                 ; ---X----  unused
                 ; ----1---  accept standard or extended according to filters
                 ; -----X--  unused
                 ; ------00  acceptance mask 1 bits 

         setreg  b'00000000', rxm1sidh
                 ; 00000000  acceptance mask 1 bits 

         setreg  b'00000000', rxm1eidl
                 ; 00000000  acceptance mask 1 bits 

         setreg  b'00000000', rxm1eidh
                 ; 00000000  acceptance mask 1 bits 

         setreg  b'00000001', rxfcon0
                 ; 0-------  disable filter 7
                 ; -0------  disable filter 6
                 ; --0-----  disable filter 5
                 ; ---0----  disable filter 4
                 ; ----0---  disable filter 3
                 ; -----0--  disable filter 2
                 ; ------0-  disable filter 1
                 ; -------1  enable filter 0

         setreg  b'00000001', rxfcon1
                 ; 0-------  disable filter 15
                 ; -0------  disable filter 14
                 ; --0-----  disable filter 13
                 ; ---0----  disable filter 12
                 ; ----0---  disable filter 11
                 ; -----0--  disable filter 10
                 ; ------0-  disable filter 9
                 ; -------1  enable filter 8

         setreg  b'00000000', sdflc
                 ; XXX-----  unused
                 ; ---00000  number of data bits to compare to filter for standard message

         setreg  b'00000000', msel0
                 ; 00------  filter 3 associated with mask 0
                 ; --00----  filter 2 associated with mask 0
                 ; ----00--  filter 1 associated with mask 0
                 ; ------00  filter 0 associated with mask 0

         setreg  b'00000000', msel1
                 ; 00------  filter 7 associated with mask 0
                 ; --00----  filter 6 associated with mask 0
                 ; ----00--  filter 5 associated with mask 0
                 ; ------00  filter 4 associated with mask 0

         setreg  b'01010101', msel2
                 ; 01------  filter 11 associated with mask 1
                 ; --01----  filter 10 associated with mask 1
                 ; ----01--  filter 9 associated with mask 1
                 ; ------01  filter 8 associated with mask 1

         setreg  b'01010101', msel3
                 ; 01------  filter 15 associated with mask 1
                 ; --01----  filter 14 associated with mask 1
                 ; ----01--  filter 13 associated with mask 1
                 ; ------01  filter 12 associated with mask 1

         setreg  b'00000000', rxf0sidl
                 ; 000-----  standard ID bits 
                 ; ---X----  unused
                 ; ----0---  accept only standard IDs
                 ; -----X--  unused
                 ; ------00  extended ID bits 

         setreg  b'00000000', rxf0sidh
                 ; 00000000  standard ID bits 

         setreg  b'00000000', rxf0eidl
                 ; 00000000  extended ID bits 

         setreg  b'00000000', rxf0eidh
                 ; 00000000  extended ID bits 

         setreg  b'00001000', rxf8sidl
                 ; 000-----  standard ID bits 
                 ; ---X----  unused
                 ; ----1---  accept only extended IDs
                 ; -----X--  unused
                 ; ------00  extended ID bits 

         setreg  b'00000000', rxf8sidh
                 ; 00000000  standard ID bits 

         setreg  b'00000000', rxf8eidl
                 ; 00000000  extended ID bits 

         setreg  b'00000000', rxf8eidh
                 ; 00000000  extended ID bits 
;
;   Done configuring the CAN module.  Switch it from configuration mode to
;   normal operating mode.
;
         setreg  b'00000000', cancon ;set up CAN module for normal operation
                 ; 000-----  request normal operating mode
                 ; ---0----  don't abort pending transmissions
                 ; ----XXXX  read-only status bits
;
;   Start CAN receiving task.
;
         task_create can_task, stack_can

         leaverest
```

Perhaps you can see something you are doing differently.  This code assumes the existance of my standard macro library and that it will be run thru my PIC assembler preprocessor before being passed to MPASM.  You can probably infer most of what it's doing, but the preprocessor documentation is available at http://www.embedinc.com/pic/prepic.txt.htm.

Comment: Trying to open http://www.embedinc.com/pic/prepic.txt.htm, Firefox reports: "This web page at www.embedinc.com has been reported to contain unwanted software and has been blocked based on your security preferences." I very seldomly get this message, perhaps once per year.

Comment: @Peter: Yes, some of the less careful virus checkers get a false positive on some of the software we provide.  A few years ago, something apparently changed in one of our low level libraries to match a signature these virus programs are looking for.  I can assure you that there is no malicious code on our site.